# Migrate Matlab command history from 7 versions to 8 versions

Tags: matlab

I recently installed a new version of of Matlab (8.3 -- 2014a).
Previously I use 7.13 -- 2011b. While I wanted to migrate my old command history and directory history to the new installation, I found that they used a different format to store it.

The version before 2011b store the command history in history.m under prefdir, while 2014a store it in History.xml.

Is there any fast way to import the old history into the new Matlab versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. winopen(prefdir)
2. copy your previous version of matlab's history.m file here
3. rename or delete the existing history.xml
4. A new history.xml will be created based on history.m on next run of Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

In your older version of **MATLAB** type **winopen(perfdir)**. This command will open a folder containing file **History.xml**. Copy this file.

Now type in the dame command in new **MATAB**. Copy and over-write the **History.xml** file already present in that folder.

The command **winopen(perfdir)** is useful in case you don't know the location of file in **"Program Files"**. If you know directly copy-paste it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. winopen(prefdir) shows the folder containing the preference and history files. However, in the older version, there's only a "history.m" instead of "History.xml". They stored in  different formats and the new version doesn't recognize the old "history.m" file.

Comment: use xml to plain text conversion site like http://xmlgrid.net/xml2text.html Then copy the text into the history.m file. (This might help i haven't actually tried this.)